# Will this Project be possible? / ROS Time Syncronisation

Tags: kinect, sensor-msgs, rosmaster, rostime, timesynchronizer

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi Guys,

I would like to discuss the doability of a project. I want to run a couple of ARM Boards (Pandaboard ES) which are connected to each other with an Ethernet-switch. The Boards already run ROS electric and Ubuntu 11.10. Every board is hosting a sensor like a Kinect or Webcam. Now I want to trigger an event and every sensor should publish the data from the exact same time-stamp (synchronization of the data should be in the milliseconds range).

Will that be possible by exporting the master to a single board which is providing the ROS-Time for all other nodes.
Did I get I right that the Timestamps in the Sensor_msgs depend on the ROS-Time and so it should be possible to obtain data from the exact same time stamp or will I encounter a summation of time delays?
Or does the timestamp in the sensor_msgs header depend on the system time? Is there a way to use the clock just from a single board

It would be great to here about your expertise/opinion.

Cheers

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/40792/will-this-project-be-possible?-/-ros-time-syncronisation/) by [dinamex](https://answers.ros.org/users/1383/dinamex/) on ROS Answers with karma: 447 on 2012-08-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

- ROS on ARM

Which ARM devices are you talking about? ROS on ARM is in some cases possible (e.g. running a Linux system on an ARM board, such as the Beagleboard), but there aren't many user out there AFAIK. This Q&A gives an insight: http://answers.ros.org/question/10716/ros-on-arm/

- Synchronisation

As cagatay already mentioned, you will need to sync your machines (your ARM boards) by hand or with tools like chrony.
A Q&A on this topic: http://answers.ros.org/question/11180/chrony-configuration-and-limitations/

Regarding the actual synchronisation of your data, you have to keep in mind that the data is usually time-stamped on creation. Once you request data, you would get **the most recent one**. So you need to implement some mechanism to align your data. I recommend to look around for existing code & projects, since data synchronisation is common problem.

But after all, I say, yes it is possible! :-)

---

Originally posted by [bit-pirate](https://answers.ros.org/users/62/bit-pirate/) with karma: 2062 on 2012-08-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dinamex](https://answers.ros.org/users/1383/dinamex/) on 2012-08-09**:
So the timestamp in each header of an sensor_msgs depends on the systemclock one the machine and not on the ROS-Master?

**Comment by [dinamex](https://answers.ros.org/users/1383/dinamex/) on 2012-08-09**:
for the ARM part see the edited Question.

**Comment by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) on 2012-08-09**:
Yes, ROS times are relative to the system clock, not the time on the master (unless you are using sim_time, but that is for simulation). You sync computer clocks with something like ntp or chrony. Also, you need to make sure your sensors are triggerable - I don't think the Kinect is.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

have you tried using ntp or chrony ?

---

Originally posted by [cagatay](https://answers.ros.org/users/2526/cagatay/) with karma: 1850 on 2012-08-07

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dinamex](https://answers.ros.org/users/1383/dinamex/) on 2012-08-07**:
Thank you for the answer. Do I need to sync the clocks of all boards even when I export the ROS-MASTER?

**Comment by [cagatay](https://answers.ros.org/users/2526/cagatay/) on 2012-08-07**:
I guess, you may encounter problem with various computers running ros. check the network setup for ros, fifth topic is related with your question as far as i understand http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/NetworkSetup